# Yii2 Rest - Custom action and OPTIONS method

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm having trouble with the following action "/login" route action in my UsersController class

```
public function actionLogin(){
        $data = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
        $model = new Usuario();

        //Validamos que se hayan recibido los campos
        if(empty($data['email']) || empty($data['password'])){
            throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException("Debe ingresar email y password");
        }

        //Validamos usuario y contraseña
        $usuario = $model->findByUsername($data['email']);
        if(empty($usuario) || !$usuario->validatePassword($data['password'])){
            throw new \yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos");
        }
        return $usuario;
    }
```

The situation is that I'm using POST method to perform login, and I'm calling this route from a different domain, so the frontend library first try to call /login route with OPTIONS method to check if it is allowed or not to call /login with POST..

The problem is that the built in functionality of yii2 rest ActiveController is only for /users and /users/{id}

If I manually add this /login route to be available in both POST and OPTIONS through actions verbFilter, then yii Is trying to actually call the login action with the OPTIONS request. I mean, it is trying to perform login. Of course it can't, because it is not sending email and passwords fields, but I can see an error in the log file.

So, my question is... Is there any way to configure correctly this "custom" routes actions and make OPTIONS performs transparently? Because I'm expecting that login action not get executed when calling it with OPTIONS, but instead to return directly the OPTIONS allowed methods headers.

**Update Info: Added URL manager rules**

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => true,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => ['v1/users'],
                'pluralize' => false,
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ]
            ],
            //Rutas usuario
            'v1/login' => '/v1/users/login'
        ],        
    ],
```

Answer (score 7):

By default the `yii\rest\UrlRule` class will apply those patterns to any endpoint :

```
'patterns' => [
    'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',
    'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
    'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view',
    'POST' => 'create',
    'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
    '{id}' => 'options',
    '' => 'options',
]
```

Which means that any request holding OPTIONS verbs will be redirected to `yii\rest\OptionsAction` if your `loginAction` is written inside a class extending **ActiveController**.

What I suggest is to override `patterns` by leaving the only used verbs as your **login** action doesn't need any of the other CRUD actions. this should work with your case :

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
        'controller' => ['v1/users'],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'tokens' => [
            '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => ['v1/login' => '/v1/users/login'],
        'patterns' => [
            'POST' => 'login',
            '' => 'options',
        ]
    ] 
],
```

NOTE: the solution by @CreatoR is also a requirement here and exactly as he did it without defining keys. otherwise OPTIONS verbs will be rejected if not authenticated.

---

In case if your **login** action is defined under a class extending `yii\rest\Controller` directly instead of passing through `yii\rest\ActiveController` (which should be appropriate for authentication actions as there is no CRUD needed here) then the same **rules** configs should work fine but you'll need to manually add the **actionOptions** to your code :

```
// grabbed from yii\rest\OptionsAction with a little work around
private $_verbs = ['POST','OPTIONS'];

public function actionOptions ()
{
    if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(405);
    }
    $options = $this->_verbs;
    Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', implode(', ', $options));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue.

This is how I fixed it:

I added an `extraPatterns` parameter to my rule, like this:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'pluralize' => false,
                'controller' => [
                    'athlete',
                    'admin',
                    'address',
                    'program'
                ],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'OPTIONS <action:\w+>' => 'options'
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

This way, the `options` action will be called for every custom action that I have in any of these controllers.

Comment: `Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::OPTIONS <action:\w+>` fetching this error , do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Please check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829792/yii2-rest-api-options-request-type-is-not-working

Comment: This is actually the only answer that helped me. But I also added it to the 'optional' array of the authenticater I use like so: $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => \sizeg\jwt\JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
            'except' => [ 'options' ],
            'optional' => [ 
                'opt'
            ]
        ];

Answer (score 4):

I solved issue by extending Cors filter class:

```
use Yii;
use yii\filters\Cors;

class CorsCustom extends  Cors

{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        parent::beforeAction($action);

        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', 'POST GET PUT');
            Yii::$app->end();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and then

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => CorsCustom::className(),
    ];
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'optional' => ['login']
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Comment: Then where will you add this Cors custom in the rest controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `Cors` filter in your controller's `behaviours()` method (see how [in official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html#cors)) with following conditions:

1. `Cors` filter should be defined before Authentication / Authorization filters
2. Open access for all users to action `option` in `AccessControl` filter

In your situation, `UsersController` might have such `behaviors()` method:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge(
        [
            'cors' => [
                'class' => Cors::className(),
            ],
        ],
        parent::behaviors(),
        [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                     ['allow' => true, 'actions' => ['options']],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: @CreatorR I tried your solution but it didn't worked because, I think, that you didn't understood my question.. Loking at the source code of rest ActiveController, I see that a 'yii\rest\OptionsAction' action is configured for  options method.. Is there a way to configure that when calling /login with POST it call actionLogin and when calling /login with OPTIONS then it call 'yii\rest\OptionsAction'? Which is the best way to achieve that? I think that this is what I need..

Comment: @edrian, would be great to see your urlManager rules

Comment: @edrian, I've had the same problem with OPTIONS, but it was resolved by declaring Cors behavior. Currently I can't reproduce this situation for check my idea. Better way to declare `custom` route in ActiveController described here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html (use `extraPatterns` configuration).

Answer (score 0):

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
        'controller' => ['v1/users'],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'tokens' => [
            '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => ['v1/login' => '/v1/users/login'],
        'patterns' => [
            'POST' => 'login',
            'OPTIONS' => 'options',
        ]
    ] 
],
```