# Yii2 + restapi + cors + bearer - unauthorized when creating custom controller action

Tags: rest, yii2, cors

I am making angular 2 / Yii2 app

When I call custom controller/action from Postman with bearer header, everything works fine, but when I call it with the same header from angular 2 application (localhost:4200) I get always Unauthorized 401 error.
When I do standard actions like from example from [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) like:

```
GET /users: list all users page by page;
POST /users: create a new user;
```

everything works fine, only when I create custom action, than I get unauthorized.

This is cross domain application, 
angular is available on web.example.com, 
yii2 app is on srv.example.com

```
namespace app\controllers\restapi;

use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;

class SearchOrderController extends \yii\rest\Controller
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Order';
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ];
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
                'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
                'authMethods' => [
                        HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                ],
        ];
        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        return $behaviors;
    }
    public function actionSearch(){
        \Yii::$app->response->format=\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ['index'=>'some text', 'value'=>123];
    }
}
```

Also my url manager:

```
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'order',
            'pluralize' => false,
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET order/<id:\id+>' => 'order/view',
            ]
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'search-order',
            'pluralize' => false,
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET search-order/search' => 'search-order/search',
        ]
```

Comment: are you sure GET and POST are the failing requests? could you please check your browser's network tab to see if it is not an `OPTIONS /users` the failing one?

Comment: it is OPTIONS... as message i get is:
OPTIONS http://srv.example.com/restapi/search-order/search 401 (Unauthorized)

what could i do with that?

Comment: Here's [official solution](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#cors) for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using solution posted here:

[Yii2 Rest - Custom action and OPTIONS method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447294/yii2-rest-custom-action-and-options-method)

and implementing custom Cors class:

```
<?php 
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\Cors;

class CustomCors extends  Cors

{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        parent::beforeAction($action);

        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', 'POST GET PUT');
            Yii::$app->end();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and changing my controller behaviours accordingly:

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // remove authentication filter
        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
                'class' =>CustomCors::className()
        ];

        // re-add authentication filter
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
                'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
                'authMethods' => [
                        HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                ],

        ];

        return $behaviors;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) issue. I see two things to fix here.

First you need to implement an action to respond to that request as you are extending `yii\rest\Controller`. Such action [is already implemented by Yii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/cd64fb2dc67d92d3fb8a05b402b273b07192ba1b/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php) but in its child controller `yii\rest\ActiveController`. So either you use the `actions()` function to import it like it is done [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/cd64fb2dc67d92d3fb8a05b402b273b07192ba1b/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L102-L104) or you can simply implement it directly as it is done in this other satck overflow post:

[Post Request working in Postman but returns Preflight error in Angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633212/post-request-working-in-postman-but-returns-preflight-error-in-angular-2-app/41723864#41723864)

Then you'll need to define their related rules:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'order',
    'pluralize' => false,
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET order/<id:\id+>' => 'order/view',
        'OPTIONS order/<id:\id+>' => 'order/options',
    ]
],
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'search-order',
    'pluralize' => false,
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET search-order/search' => 'search-order/search',
        'OPTIONS search-order/search' => 'search-order/options',
]
```

Next you'll need to let your authentication allowing preflight requests as the browser won't send any token with them. by adding this line as shown in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors):

```
// avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
$behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
```